# JavaScript helper functions calling eachother

Tags: javascript

I have a collection of helper-functions, like this:

```
var myHelpers = {

    addFoo: ( name ) => {
        return name + 'foo';
    },

    addFooBar: ( name ) => {
        return this.addFoo( name ) + 'bar'; // This is what throws the error.
    }

}

window.myHelpers = myHelpers;
export default myHelpers;
```

And I then use it like this:

```
import myHelpers from "./myHelpers";

let test = 'abc';
test = myHelpers.addFooBar( test );
```

But this throws the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`

... How do I make these functions call eachother, without getting this error?

Comment: Use a regular function instead of an arrow function

Comment: _Use a regular function instead of an arrow function..._ Can you please explain why? @Reyno

Comment: @B001ᛦ There is a duplicate answer which explains this very well. But here is an (extremely short) explanation: normal functions redefine `this` while arrow functions do not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `myHelpers` instead of `this`

```
addFooBar: name => {
  return myHelpers.addFoo(name) + 'bar'
},
```